# Amazon Redshift, will the free trial be lost if first cluster is shut down?

Tags: amazon-redshift

Amazon Redshift has a free trial for two months for a cluster with a new account. Will the free trial be lost if the cluster is shutdown with a snapshot, and restored from that snapshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done that, the trial period is not lost. It even remains if you remove the cluster and create a new one.